# How many turns does an average game of Checkers/Draughts go for?

Tags: checkers

How many turns does a checkers/draughts tend to last for, in the the American/English variation, on an 8x8 board?

I've been trying to google it but I can only find answers related to chess.

Comment: This is actually quite broad, but i believe that it can take on average about  15 - 45 min depending on skill level and thinking time.

Comment: Maybe it would be less broad if the OP clarified whether they were asking about how many turns are taken by players or wall clock time.  It would seem like the number of turns per game could be determined from analyzing historic games.

Comment: @chicks Hi! I am talking about actual turns, now that you mention it I see how ambiguous the question is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [The American Checker Federation](http://www.usacheckers.com/index.php)

The ACF has the transcripts for a lot of games. By my count, they have `9,374` games recorded from 1952 to 2009. These are available for [download](http://www.usacheckers.com/show_game_start.php). In these 10k games, there has been `460,381` moves made. Thus an average* game of checkers takes `49.11` moves or `24.56` moves per color.

Here is a summary:

```
White Wins:  1596
Draw:        5406
Black Wins:  2372
-----------------
Total Games: 9374

Total Moves:      460381
Moves/Game:       49.11
Moves/Game/Color: 24.56
```

<sup>* average game between two ACF players</sup>